# Problem with script in lua, Error nil value (local 'xPlayer')

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto

so when i try to buy something in shop it's just drop me this error.How to fix this?
Code:

```
RegisterServerEvent('esx_shops:buyItem')
AddEventHandler('esx_shops:buyItem', function(itemName, amount, zone)
    local _source = source
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)
    local sourceItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(itemName)

    amount = ESX.Round(amount)

    -- is the player trying to exploit?
    if amount < 0 then
        print('esx_shops: ' .. xPlayer.identifier .. ' attempted to exploit the shop!')
        return
    end
```

Error:

```
SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_supermarket/server/main.lua:68: attempt to index a nil value (local 'xPlayer')
```

Comment: `if amount < 0 then and xPlayer then ...` or before, just check `xPlayer`

Comment: I edited to this: https://pastebin.com/dJT8h83V and now i have this error: 
"SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_supermarket/server/main.lua:98: attempt to index a nil value (global 'soureItem')"

Comment: you need just return from script: `if not xPlayer  then return end` in 68 line. i think.

Comment: Could you edit the code? Because I don't understand what you mean, I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

`xPlayer` is a `nil` value. `nil` values may not be indexed. Doing so causes an error.

So anything like `xPlayer[something]`, `xPlayer.something` or `xPlayer:something()` is not allowed.

In your first example

```
local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)
    local sourceItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(itemName)
```

`xPlayer` is `nil` because `ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)` did not return a player. Most likely because `_source` is `nil`. At least there is nothing in your code that would indicate that `source` is not `nil`.

Befor you try to index possible `nil` values, check wether they are `nil`.

Please read the Lua manual and do a beginners tutorial.